# Is there a way to see if there is only numbers in a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do error checking on a form.  I wanted to see if a phone number is valid by if it has all numbers in it.  Is there a way to see if a string only has nmbers in it?

Comment: Just making sure, it's not a HTML form? Either way: of course there is. One way would be a pattern/regex. You should do your research.

Comment: Regular expressions would be one choice to allow strings like "(385)-141-3423" to be accepted.

Comment: depends can you add a sample accepted number format.

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to check for a pattern as well. Then you can check ASCII values of each digit/char in a loop. `if(string.charAt(i) < 48 || string.charAt(i) > 58){//Not number}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **regex** for this:

```
if(value.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    System.out.println("Only numbers!");
}
```

Comment: ...so you're saying that if I submit a numerical value, it will return "Only numbers!"?? Your `if` statement may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern for validating phone number with regex

```
"\\d{3}-\\d{7}"
```

for example:

```
 310-6666666
```

**or**

if you want just to read integer from your string

```
public class Agent{
 public static void main(String...args){
    String input = "1 23 35 5d 8 0 f";
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")).stream().forEach( i -> {
        try{
          intList.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
});

intList.forEach( i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

}

ouput:

```
1 23 35 8 0
```